# Slickgrid force columns to fit viewport size when enablecolumnorder equals false and resizable equals false?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have created numerous slickgrids, but this is the first one that I am creating that I need to have the columns not be resizable and reorderable (draggable).  What I really need is for my columns to fit my viewport at all times but not be resizable/reorderable, and not extend horizontally during a screen resize (increase or decrease).

I have found that if I put this into the column options. :'

```
resizable: false
```

This will stop them from being resized but upon doing this it resizes my columns on page load to width I specified per column.  Which is normally what I would want, but I have a specific width of 1300px for my viewport.  So, if I set my pixels just right the grid will behave nicely in the viewport and look great.  However, this application that I am working on requires the ability to minimize or maximize the screen, upon doing so my columns which are now set to a specific width remain that width and a horizontal scrollbar appears pushing my columns past the 1300px range.

If I remove column widths and keep forcefitcolumns and then my columns are really tiny and it just looks terrible.

Example of one of my columns. :

```
{ id: "Mode", name: "Mode", field: "Mode", width: 125, sortable: true, formatter: TaskNameFormatter, editor: Slick.Editors.Text, resizable: false },
```

Example of my grid options. :

```
var GridOptions = {
        showHeaderRow: true,
        showHeaderRow: true,
        headerRowHeight: 30,
        explicitInitialization: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        enableTextSelectionOnCells: true,
        forceFitColumns: true,
        multiColumnSort: true,
        topPanelHeight: 25,
        autoHeight: true,
        enableColumnReorder: false
    };
```

Example of my grid div. :

```
<div id="slickGrid" class="grid-body" style="min-width: 800px; max-width: 1300px; height: auto;"></div>
```

And obviously I have the grid resize. :

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  Grid.resizeCanvas();
});
```

I am just wondering how you handle this situation, basically I need my columns to fill the viewport horizontally and maintain that size even during a window resize.  Thoughts?  Has anyone defeated this issue before?  If I could just figure out how to dynamically keep my columns the appropriate size for the viewport I could call that again during a window resize.

***Note I have also tried the Grid.autosizeColumns and setting the min-width of each column and these do not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/17
```

Found this seems to be doing the trick. :

You need to change the conditional for column resize attribute:

```
!c.resizable
```

to:

```
(!c.resizable && options.forceFitColumns !== true)
```

Per user  tobiasstrebitzer